# Next router: How to access multiple query parameters?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

OS: Windows 10 Pro
react: "^16.5.2"
next: "^7.0.2"
next-with-apollo: "^3.1.3"

So I'm having an issue with the query part of router.push whereby only the first defined query prop is detected but anything after is `undefined:

```html
import Router from 'next/router';

Router.push({
  pathname: '/order',
  query: { id: order.data.createOrder.id, onToken: "true" },
});
```

In `order` I can access id by `this.props.id` but trying to access onToken via  `this.props.onToken` reads as `undefined`.

What's the issue here?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.props.query.whatever`?

Answer (score 0):

So I wrapped my component in `withRouter()` and accessed the individual parameters by calling `this.props.router.query`.